# Liquibase maven plugin: cannot find the databasechangelog table, PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, maven, liquibase

I am using the liquibase maven plugin (version 3.10.0) and I am trying to apply the existing migrations. Before applying migrations I create the database, using the simple sql `create database test`

After that, I execute the following maven command

`>mvn liquibase:update -Dliquibase.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test?currentSchema=public -Dliquibase.username=postgres -Dliquibase.password=postgres -Dliquibase.context=dev`

However, upon the completion, I've got the following error

`[ERROR] Could not release lock liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL UPDATE databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = FALSE, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1: ERROR: relation "databasechangeloglock" does not exist`

`Error executing SQL SELECT MAX(ORDEREXECUTED) FROM databasechangelog: ERROR: relation "databasechangelog" does not exist`

My liquibase maven plugin configuration is the following

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <databaseChangeLogLockTableName>databasechangeloglock</databaseChangeLogLockTableName>
                    <databaseChangeLogTableName>databasechangelog</databaseChangeLogTableName>
                    <changelogSchemaName>public</changelogSchemaName>
                    <defaultSchemaName>public</defaultSchemaName>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And I placed this configuration into the dedicated maven module.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, it turn out to be postgresql db jar version issue, try updating your pom with latest postgresql driver jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```